# Best way to define months as array elements from a date range

Tags: php, optimization

I trying to define an array containing all months from a certain date range (like 2015-03-01 and 2017-03-01).
The result I'm looking for is:

```
Array
(
    ['2015'] => Array
    (
        ['03'] => 0
        ['04'] => 0
        ['05'] => 0
        ['06'] => 0
        ['07'] => 0
        ['08'] => 0
        ['09'] => 0
        ['10'] => 0
        ['11'] => 0
        ['12'] => 0
    )
    ['2016'] => Array
    (
        ['01'] => 0
        ['02'] => 0
        ['03'] => 0
        ['04'] => 0
        ['05'] => 0
        ['06'] => 0
        ['07'] => 0
        ['08'] => 0
        ['09'] => 0
        ['10'] => 0
        ['11'] => 0
        ['12'] => 0
    )
    ['2017'] => Array
    (
        ['01'] => 0
        ['02'] => 0
        ['03'] => 0
    )
)
```

Which way would be the best way to do it?
Note: This is a dummy example, just looking for the best practice.

Comment: i wouldn't care about optimization at all in this case... you are not working with commodore 64, current computer will be fine with any format you'll choose. look after code quality instead optimization

Comment: Avoid using numbers with a leading zero as keys for your array keys.... a leading zero means an octal number: `08` and `09` are invalid octal, and will cause you problems

Comment: I made a dummy example, the real array is much bigger. I'm also asking for the best practice.
About the keys, it's an associative array which has to be used in the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

Some simple things to start off with

- use `32-bit int` instead of `strings`
- make the entire things with the years, months and date on Continuos memory (very good for caching)
- if possible make it matrix-free, that means you know a year has 12 months; so why bother reserving memory for that redundant information?